# Ping script witch up or down status

Tags: shell, ping

Wy dosent work?
I'm learning bash scripting but this ping operation dosent work i dont know wy, some one can give me a light please?

```
#!/bin/bash
r1="<UP>!"
r2="<DOWN>!"
if ! ping -c 1 0.0.0.0
then
echo $r1
else
echo $r2 
fi
```

Comment: Because you ask "is it **NOT** up", and if so, you print `<UP>!`, but it should be the other way round (without the `!` or with the two messages reversed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "!" which negates the truth so it returns UP when DOWN and vice versa, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
r1="<UP>!"
r2="<DOWN>!"

if ping -c 1 0.0.0.1 >&1 > /dev/null ; then
    echo $r1
else
    echo $r2
fi
```

Also i've modified the ping command to ignore the usual output. Now it just displays up or down

Comment: Wow ! Worked thanks.
But the output show's me the ping stats.
How can i hide then?

PING 10.10.19.10 (10.10.19.10) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.10.19.10 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

<DOWN>!

Comment: Hello, i've edited the post, and i've added this bit of code ">&1 > /dev/null". This ignore the usual output of the ping command and just prints UP or DOWN.